# Nomogram for family of lines

Tags: nomography

Assume I have an implicit function $F(x,y,z)=0$ which can be expressed as a family of lines, i.e.
$$
F(x,y,z)=0 \quad\text{if and only if}\quad y=m(z)x+b(z)
$$
for functions $m$ and $b$.

Is it possible, for general $m$ and $b$, to put this relation into determinantal form as understood in nomography?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer without determinant.

[image]

Indeed, one can use - if it exists - the envelope curve of all these straight lines. This envelope is classicaly obtained by considering the linear system

$$\begin{cases}y&=&m(z)x+b(z) & (a)\\ 0&=&m'(z)x+b'(z) & (a')\\ \end{cases} \tag{1}$$

(where (a') is obtained by differentiation of
(a) with respect to parameter $z$).

From (1), one obtains a *parametric representation* of the envelope curve by "extracting" $x$ and then $y$ as functions of $z$ alone:

$$\begin{cases}x&=&-b'(z)/m'(z)\\ y&=&(m'(z)b(z)+m(z)b'(z))/m'(z)\\ \end{cases} \tag{2}$$

In this way, after having placed "tick marks" on this envelope, one gets all the $x$ and $y$ satisfying relationship $y=m(z)x+b(z).$

Comment: Sorry I was on on the way when I upvoted your answer. Thanks a lot, this approach looks great, I will have to see what software can generate such nomograms, at the moment I'm using PyNomo.

Answer (score 0):

After reading up on Warmus' procedure it became clear that an answer to my question is
$$
\det \left|\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & x & 0 \\ 0 & y & 1 \\ -m(z) & b(z) & 1\end{array}\right|.
$$

Comment: I would be interested to know what Warmus procedure is (though having worked on nomograms, I hadn't heard this name). Thanks.

Comment: Warmus' procedure goes back to his 1959 monograph Nomographic Functions, and provides a way to determine whether a given function is nomographable. For the current example I used the algorithmic notes at http://logical.ai/worklife/2020%20week%2001%20jan/nomo/kellogg.pdf .

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will have a look at the reference you have given. I have other references that I have to find back.

Answer (score 0):

The equation can also be nomographed directly using the [Type 10](http://lefakkomies.github.io/pynomo-doc/types/types.html#type10-ref) nomographs implemented in PyNomo.